# Tool for reversing nested emails

Tags: windows, gratis, email

Sometimes, I get forwarded a long email conversation. Then I have to read the email from the bottom up, working my way up through all of the "On [date], "person wrote" lines. This drives me a little crazy.

Is there a tool that can take either:

- an HTML file of the rendered email (from GMail print window, say) and/or
- The "original" [RFC 5332](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_format) text (as seen, e.g. in Gmail's "Show original" option")

and output HTML that effectively reverses the message order so that the older messages appear at the top of the file?

- Program should run on Windows 7+ (any dependencies OK)
- Freeware
- Can be GUI or command-line.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: Targeted OS, definition of "raw email file" (what format?), which other requirements (e.g. does it need a GUI, or shall it run from command-line?). The more details you can provide, the better tailored the answers can be. Thanks!